# Android 11 Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm working on a intruder selfie feature where if user enters incorrect phone pin my app takes selfie and send it in email. Its working on Android 9 but in Android 11 its getting error. I'm attaching the logcat.

```
2021-11-13 21:51:49.815 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure I/System.out: SAM: has camera permission
2021-11-13 21:51:49.823 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure I/System.out: SAM: findFrontFacingCamera(): 1
2021-11-13 21:51:49.837 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 1: Status(-8, EX_SERVICE_SPECIFIC): '6: connectHelper:2103: Camera "1" disabled by policy'
2021-11-13 21:51:49.838 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure I/System.out: SAM: exception1: Fail to connect to camera service
2021-11-13 21:51:49.838 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:557)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:402)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at com.pbix.quantsecure.utils.CapPhoto.openCamera(CapPhoto.java:206)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at com.pbix.quantsecure.utils.CapPhoto.onStartCommand(CapPhoto.java:142)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4741)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:301)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2186)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
2021-11-13 21:51:49.839 28831-28831/com.pbix.quantsecure W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)


private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void openCamera(){
        try{
            if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2 && cam.equals("f")) {
//                mCamera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                System.out.println("SAM: findFrontFacingCamera(): "+findFrontFacingCamera());
                mCamera = Camera.open(findFrontFacingCamera());
            }
            if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2 && cam.equals("b")) {
                mCamera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            }
            if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() < 2) {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("SAM: exception1: "+e.getMessage());
            Util.recordEx(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//        SurfaceView sv = null;
//        try {
//            sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
//        }catch (Exception e){
//            System.out.println("SAM: exception2: "+e.getMessage());
//            Util.recordEx(e);
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        try {
            SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
            parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

            SurfaceTexture st = new SurfaceTexture(MODE_PRIVATE);
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(st);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
            sHolder = sv.getHolder();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SAM: exception2: "+e.getMessage());
            Util.recordEx(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            timerSendSMS = new Timer();
            timerSendSMS.schedule(new CapPhoto.taskSendSMS(), 0, 2 * 60 * 1000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SAM: exception3: "+e.getMessage());
            Util.recordEx(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You appear to be doing this from a service; there are background restrictions on camera access. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services) for the `foregroundServiceTypes` that you need.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for your reply. But it doesn't provide any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) thanks to CommonsWare :)

```html
<manifest>
    <service ... android:foregroundServiceType="location|camera" />
</manifest>
```